# Prevent docker image from being used concurrently

Tags: docker, security

I am interested in setting up a docker image that will be read only and not possible to be accessed concurrently multiple times. In other words, while that docker image is running, it should not allow other sessions (same or different user) to log to it and access the data inside it or interact with it and it should also not write anything permanently and stick to its initial state. This is for security reasons for a particular scenario.

For the read only part, I assume I could simply do:

```
docker run — read-only [image-name]
```

I am not sure how to prevent the multiple concurrent sessions case though.

Comment: Docker is exactly made to allow for concurrent containers, provided they don't "overlap". By running only once I assume you mean one instance per host? Preventing other systems from running the same container is nigh impossible. If you want to make sure that the host only has one occurrence, you will need to tighten up the orchestration. You can use something like Kubernetes for this, whereby you can restrict the deployment to 1 pod with 1 instance. Added benefit is that when the pod goes down a new one can be created automatically.

Comment: Yes, one instance per host.